# Taylor Diagram MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I have a question regarding generating Taylor diagram by 
           Matlab. I have three pair of various observation data sets to compare by the 
           Taylor Diagram. When I run the program (in Matlab), I have trouble 
           overlapping Taylor diagrams of each pair. What I see at the end in the graph is only the last pair.
Here is the code:

```
clear all
close all

load /Users/penny/Desktop/file_JAN16.csv
val1 = file_JAN16(:,2);
val2 = file_JAN16(:,3);
val3  = file_JAN16(:,4);    
val4 = file_JAN16(:,5);
val5  = file_JAN16(:,6);
val6  = file_JAN16(:,7);

for i = 2:size(file_JAN16,2)
   C = allstats(file_JAN16(:,2),file_JAN16(:,3));
   statm(i,:) = C(:,2);
end
for ii = 2:size(file_JAN16,2)
   C1 = allstats(file_JAN16(:,4),file_JAN16(:,5));
   statm1(ii,:) = C1(:,2);   
end 
for iii = 2:size(file_JAN16,2)
   C2 = allstats(file_JAN16(:,6),file_JAN16(:,7));
   statm2(iii,:) = C2(:,2);   
end    

statm(1,:) = C(:,1);
statm1(1,:) = C1(:,1);
statm2(1,:) = C2(:,1);

%%
figure(1)
[pp tt axl] = 
taylordiag(squeeze(statm(:,2)),squeeze(statm(:,3)),squeeze(statm(:,4)),...
        'tickRMS' 
[0.01:0.1:1],'titleRMS',0,'tickRMSangle',1,'showlabelsRMS',0,'widthRMS',1,..
        'tickSTD',[0.01:0.1:1],'limSTD',1,...
        'tickCOR',[.1:.1:.9 .95 .99],'showlabelsCOR',1,'titleCOR',1);
hold on        
figure(2) 
[pp tt axl] = 
taylordiag(squeeze(statm1(:,2)),squeeze(statm1(:,3)),squeeze(statm1(:,4)),..
        'tickRMS', 
[0.01:0.1:1],'titleRMS',0,'tickRMSangle',1,'showlabelsRMS',0,'widthRMS',1,..
        'tickSTD',[0.01:0.1:1],'limSTD',1,...
        'tickCOR',[.1:.1:.9 .95 .99],'showlabelsCOR',1,'titleCOR',1); 
hold on
figure(3)     
[pp tt axl] = 
taylordiag(squeeze(statm2(:,2)),squeeze(statm2(:,3)),squeeze(statm2(:,4)),..
        'tickRMS', 
[0.01:0.1:1],'titleRMS',0,'tickRMSangle',1,'showlabelsRMS',0,'widthRMS',1,..
        'tickSTD',[0.01:0.1:1],'limSTD',1,...
        'tickCOR',[.1:.1:.9 .95 .99],'showlabelsCOR',1,'titleCOR',1);

%%
```

There are two extra function/programs that I have borrowed from MATLAB exchange website.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. PennyP.

Comment: When I run the program (in Matlab), I have trouble 
           overlapping Taylor diagrams of each pair. What I see at the end in 
           the graph is only one point for the last pair. The other two points 
           for the the first two pair were hidden. Unless, I show them in separate 
           diagrams! I would like to have them all in one diagram.

Comment: Taylor Diagram:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_diagram